# Linq Sub Select Data Type

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Learning Linq is going to be the death of me, hahahaha.

I have a large query to retrieve data for a report. I need to add a sub query to get related data into the result set. The data in the subquery is a float in the database. My error is "Cannot convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'float'"

The query is:

```
var results = from d in db.Deliveries
join j in db.Jobs on d.Job equals j.Job1
join c in db.Customers on j.Customer equals c.Customer1
join ml in db.Material_Locations on j.Part_Number equals ml.Material into t1
from t2 in t1.DefaultIfEmpty()
join uv in db.User_Values on j.User_Values equals uv.User_Values into t3
from t4 in t3.DefaultIfEmpty()
where d.Promised_Date >= calFrom.SelectedDate && d.Promised_Date <= calTo.SelectedDate
where d.Remaining_Quantity > 0
where (t2.Location_ID ?? "") != "MSSICONSMT"
orderby d.Job, c.Name, d.Promised_Date
select new
{
      d.Promised_Date,
      d.Job,
      LocationID = t2.Location_ID ?? "",
      d.Shipped_Quantity,
      d.Remaining_Quantity,
      d.Promised_Quantity,
      j.Unit_Price,
      on_Hand_Qty = ((double?)t2.On_Hand_Qty) ?? 0.0,
      Part_Number = j.Part_Number ?? "",
      c.Name,
      c.Ship_Lead_Days,
      SafetyStk = t4.Decimal1 ?? 0.0,
      ShipDate = d.Promised_Date.AddDays(-1 * (c.Ship_Lead_Days ?? 0)),
      RemainValue = d.Remaining_Quantity * j.Unit_Price,
      Balance = d.Remaining_Quantity > 0 ? d.Remaining_Quantity - (((double?)t2.On_Hand_Qty) ?? 0.0) : 0,
      Consignment = ((float)(from x in db.Material_Locations
                        join jx in db.Jobs on x.Material equals jx.Part_Number
                        where jx.Job1 == d.Job
                                && x.Location_ID == "MSSICONSMT"
                        select new {x.On_Hand_Qty}))
};
```

The problem is the "Consignment" line in the select. How do I deal with the anonymous type and get to converted into a float?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `select new {(float)x.On_Hand_Qty}` instead of casting the IQueryable.

Comment: Also, not related to your question, but you should really be pushing this kind of query logic down to your DBMS, maybe through a stored procedure or view.

Comment: Can't change the DB, is an outside database.

Answer (score 0):

Try following :

```
Consignment = (from x in db.Material_Locations
               join jx in db.Jobs on x.Material equals jx.Part_Number
               where jx.Job1 == d.Job && x.Location_ID == "MSSICONSMT"
               select new {qty = (float)x.On_Hand_Qty}).ToList();
```

Comment: The given code compiles, but now when I run I have to convert Consignment into a double to put into a datatable. When I try to assign this value to a double field in the datatable I get an error of "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType18`1[System.Single]]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType18`1[System.Single]]> in Consignment Column.  Expected type is Double." I tried using Convert.ToDouble but with no success.

Comment: Change From : select new {qty = (double)x.On_Hand_Qty}).ToList(); To : select (float)x.On_Hand_Qty).ToList();

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Single]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.Couldn't store <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Single]> in Consignment Column.  Expected type is Double.

Comment: I ran the query through LinqPad and noticed that many times the value is a null.

Comment: Change (float) to (float?)

Answer (score 0):

```
Consignment = (from x in db.Material_Locations
                                     where x.Material == j.Part_Number
                                         && x.Location_ID == "MSSICONSMT"
                                     select (float?)x.On_Hand_Qty ?? 0.0).ToList()
```

and I had to add this;

```
newRow["Consignment"] = thisRow.Consignment.FirstOrDefault();
```

to store it in the datatable.

Thanks to all who nudge me in the right direction.